# Read input for bash script

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I'm learning shell scripting, and i want to get input for variable

```
mynum
```

My script is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

mynum

echo -n "Please enter the number to validate--->"
read mynum

if [ mynum -eq 100 ]
then
    echo "mynum is equal to 100"
else
    echo "mynum is not equal to 100"
fi
```

Help me on this.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the number to validate :" mynum

if [ mynum -eq 100 ]
then
 echo "mynum is equal to 100"
else
 echo "mynum is not equal to 100"
fi`                                                                    I have corrected the again.but i get this error.  `Please enter the number to validate :234
./is: line 5: [: mynum: integer expression expected
mynum is not equal to 100`

Answer (score 4):

Finally i got it !!!

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the number to validate :" mynum

#mynum=234

if [ $mynum -eq 100 ]
then
    echo "mynum is equal to 100"
else
    echo "mynum is not equal to 100"
fi



./is
Please enter the number to validate :345
mynum is not equal to 100
```